# Redirect from example.com to www.example.com if a certificate for example.com is invalid

Tags: linux, ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I have no valid SSL certificate for my "example.com".

**I can't issue/renew a certificate for "example.com" at the moment.**

However, I have a valid one for "www.example.com"

**I want all the requests, including https ones, to "example.com" to be redirected to "www.example.com"**

I've set up everything in nginx but when I go to "example.com", I see "invalid certificate" and don't get redirected to the **https: //www....**

```
  server {
      listen 80 default_server;
      listen [::]:80 default_server;
      server_name www.example.com example.com;
      return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
  }

  server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name localhost example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
  }

  server {
      listen 443 ssl default_server;
      listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

      server_name www.example.com;

      ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;

      # .................
```

Is there a way to fix that?

That is, redirect everything to https://www.example.com without a certificate error at https://example.com .

Comment: Do not use existing domains you don't own as examples. `example.com` is specifically reserved for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. If you don't have a valid cert for `example.com`, you can't connect to it without an error message, including redirects to a site with a valid cert. If this would be possible, this would subvert a large portion of the security TLS provides.

What stops you from getting a free [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) cert? 10 minutes, and the problem is fixed.

Comment: dns redirect to "www" or anything like that?

Comment: There is no such thing as a DNS redirect.

Comment: `What stops you from getting a free Let's Encrypt cert? ` ---> 'too many requests, wait for 1 week"

Comment: To prevent the "too many requests", Let's Encrypt has a staging endpoint to test and verify before requesting a real certificate.